# Is there a way, in BigQuery, to generate an array with the last three days of the previous quarter?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way, in BigQuery, to generate an array containing the “last three days of the months of the previous quarter”? For example, if I’m on partition `20200110`, the array would be `(2019-12-31, 2019-11-30, 2019-10-31)`. The current date is in the format `YYYYMMDD` above and can be found in the table name "project.dataset.table_YYYYMMDD".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider below DATE functions.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(
         SELECT LAST_DAY(
                  DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20200110'), QUARTER) 
                  - INTERVAL n MONTH
                )
           FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) n
       ) last_days;
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

**Query result**

[image]